# Meaning/significance of ほおに手をやる

Tags: grammar, culture

The girls are discussing whether the temporary teacher will remember their face, and then:

> 「名前はどうかな」
>   「どうかなァ...」  (the ellipsis is as written in the book)
>   たまちゃんがそうつぶやいてほおに手をやった。
>   "How about my name?"
>   "How about ..."
>   muttered Tama, and *put* her hand to her cheek.

This is not the first time I've seen ほおに手をやる and I'm not sure what to make of it.

How should I translate やる?

What significance does this action have?

I get the impression that it might be an action you make while you are thinking deeply. Is this a cultural thing or just a trait of this character? Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this situation, maybe she looks like this:

[image]
(taken from [here](http://free-photos.gatag.net/2013/08/05/130000.html))

You're right that it's a gesture people take when they're reflecting on something. We also call it in one word [頬杖](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/202951/meaning/m0u/).

> *How should I translate やる?*

[やる](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/223431/meaning/m0u/%E3%82%84%E3%82%8B/) has a sense "move something toward", thus: 目をやる "look at", 手をやる "put hand on", 人をやる "send out somebody to" etc.

But as やる has a great number of meanings, you can't expect it comes to this meaning every time you see this collocation.